# How can a camera takes 8MP pictures in a SoC with 5MP support only?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, camera, sensors

In general specifications of  [Mediatek MT6572](http://www.mediatek.com/en/products/mobile-communications/smartphone1/mt6572/), it supports up to 5MP camera, but this product [Yezz Andy A4M](http://www.gsmarena.com/yezz_andy_a4m-5912.php) is supposed to support 8MP camera which is theorically not possible unless the camera is extraploated or (interpolated)

- Is it possible for MT6572 to support an 8MP camera?
- If the camera is extrapolated (interpolated), which part of Android is responsible for this?
- Can someone know the real cameras sensor capacity ? and how?